# Can I sell an android APK by myself?

Tags: android, apk

If I have a private key and a developer account, can I sell my Android application without uploading it to the Android Market? Is there a maximum number of copies I can sell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly sell it private. There is no limit to the number of copies you may sell.